# How to define the data source for a DataTables column that is an element of an array?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

This is in a C# ASP.NET MVC 5 web application.  jQuery version 1.10.2.  DataTables jQuery plugin version 1.10.21.

A page in the web application uses a DataTable.  The DataTable is configured for server-side processing mode.  So, when it receives a response from the server, the data for a row in the table is an object like the following example.  (It is not proper JSON syntax;  I am trying to represent what I see in the watch window of the browser's debugger.)  i.e., each row has a string name, and an array of grade objects.

```
row: {...} 
    Id: 42
    Name: "Fred"
    Grades: (3) [...]
        0: {...}
            Id: 101
            Name: "Quiz 1"
            Value: "A"
        1: {...}
            Id: 102
            Name: "Homework 2"
            Value: "B"
        2: {...}
            Id: 103
            Name: "Exam 3"
            Value: "C"
        length: 3
```

In the DataTable, I want 4 columns:  one for the name, and 3 for the several grades, like the following example.

```
Name     Quiz 1     Homework 2     Exam 3
=========================================
Fred     A          B              C
```

My problem is that I cannot determine the correct notation for the data source for each of the grade columns, so that when a cell in such a column is rendered that the callback function receives an object that contains data about the grade.  The following is what I have tried in the `CSHTML` file for the page.  (I provide the number of grades to the page via a `ViewBag` property.)

```
...
    <table id="gradebook-table" class="table">
      ...
    </table>
...

<script>
  $( document ).ready( onPageReady );

  function onPageReady()
  {
    var options = {};
    options.serverSide = true;
    options.ajax =
    {
      'url': '@Url.Content( "~/gradebook/load" )',
      'type': 'POST',
    };

    var c = 0;
    options.columnDefs = [
      { targets: c++, data: "Id", visible: false, searchable: false },
      { targets: c++, data: "Name" },
    ];

    for ( var i = 0; i < @ViewBag.GradeCount; i++ )
    {
      var def = {};
      def.targets = c++;
      def.data = "Grades[" + i + "]";
      def.render = renderGradeCell;
      options.columnDefs.push( def );
    }

    $( '#gradebook-table' ).DataTable( options );
  }


  function renderGradeCell( data, type, row, meta )
  {
    if ( type === 'display' )
    {
      // I expect data to be an object containing grade properties.
      return '<span>' + data.Value + '</span>';
    }

    return data;
  }
</script>
```

When the data source for a grade column is `"Grades[" + i + "]"`, the `data` that the `renderGradeCell()` function is given is not an object that I expected, but a string like the following.  It is just `"[object Object]0"` repeated for as many items as there are in the Grades array in the data for the whole row.

```
"[object Object]0[object Object]0[object Object]0"
```

I changed the data source for a grade column to just `"Grades[]"`.  But then, the `data` that the `renderGradeCell()` function is given is the entire Grades array for that row.

Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery 1.10? It's very insecure with many known XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: I do not know why I am using jQuery 1.10, @Dai.  It is part of the development environment I am compelled to work with.  I mentioned the jQuery version for the sake of completeness, but I do not think it is relevant to my problem.